# How to create new columns with custom split on python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame like this:

[image]

I want to split the note column and create 3 new columns that consist of the name, country and digit.

The format of the note is the same just that there can be either first name or the full name there.

I was trying to split and start from the right. Take in the digit, then the country and whatever is left should enter the "name" column.

New DataFrame is meant to look like this:

[image]

Comment: Please provide us with a [complete and verifiable](https://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of what you tried

Comment: Do you have any code of your attempts?

Comment: @RahulAgarwal That is not the use-case here. We don't want them reversed. But... I have seen similar answers before to this question on SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe need [`Series.str.rsplit`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.rsplit.html) with `n=2` for spliting by only 2 last whitespaces:

```
df[['Name','Country','Digit']] = df['Note'].str.rsplit(n=2, expand=True)
```

equals too:

```
df[['Name','Country','Digit']] = df['Note'].str.rsplit(' ', n=2, expand=True)
```

Proof:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': [1,2,3,4],
    'Note': [
        'Sam John Brazil 2', 
        'Simion Canada 4',
        'Sam John Brazil 1',
        'Henry G. Hilson Spain 3']
})

df[['Name','Country','Digit']] = df['Note'].str.rsplit(n=2, expand=True)

print(df)
```

Returns:

```
   ID                     Note             Name Country  Digit
0   1        Sam John Brazil 2         Sam John  Brazil      2
1   2          Simion Canada 4           Simion  Canada      4
2   3        Sam John Brazil 1         Sam John  Brazil      1
3   4  Henry G. Hilson Spain 3  Henry G. Hilson   Spain      3
```

---

**Add this:** (if Digit column is to be numeric)

```
df['Digit'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Digit'], errors='coerce')
```

---

**Details:**

```
#print(df['Note'].str.rsplit(n=2, expand=True))

                 0       1  2
0         Sam John  Brazil  2
1           Simion  Canada  4
2         Sam John  Brazil  1
3  Henry G. Hilson   Spain  3
```

Comment: Smart. Probably a: `df['Digit'] = df['Digit'].astype(int)` after too.

Comment: Hello jezrael! I'm newbie on python and I was there just to learn something. Can you explain your answer please? thanks in advance

Comment: @Simo - Sure, but first need create sample data :(

Comment: @JohnZwinck That is only true if you assign a scalar to multiple cols.

Comment: @Simo do you understand it now?

Comment: If the state is state is made by 2 words(eg. `United Kingdom`) doesnt work properly :(

Comment: @Joe - Yes, you are right - possible solution is 2 repalcements like `countries2 = ['United Kingdom']
d = {x:x.replace(' ','_') for x in countries2}
d1 = {v:k for k, v in d.items()}

df[['Name','Country','Digit']] = df['Note'].replace(d, regex=True).str.rsplit(n=2, expand=True)
df['Country'] = df['Country'].replace(d1, regex=True)`